# Presenting a iOS Keyboard and Modal TextView Simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, text-editor, modal-view

So I haven't found a good answer on how to present the keyboard and a modal textview at the same time in Objective-C. One app I've seen that does this is Phonto in the app store. I'm trying to do the same thing. The cool thing about what they do is the modal view comes down from the top and the keyboard from the bottom with similar animation. Also, with an app that does this, I've been wondering how they would use auto layout to compensate for the keyboard. Does anyone know how to help me accomplish this?

[Phonto Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLleN.jpg)

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Make the text view the first responder in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: do what maddy said and then make animations using UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate